# Extremely slow HTTP data transfer [Electron]

Tags: node.js, http, download, electron

I'm developing an Electron app that download a file from my web server.

I tried downloading the exact same file from a separate NodeJS script (no Electron, just plain NodeJS)
and speeds are as to be expected: very fast.

However when I run the exact same code from withing my Electron app it is extremely slow.

Is there a know issue with Electron and data transfer issues?

Here is a visualization:
[image]

Comment: have you tried running it on a different machine ?

Comment: No, not really. But it doesn't make any sense. I also create a bare minimum web server (other than the original) that only handles the file transfer part. Still slow.

Answer (score 1):

Issue seemed to be related to `async/await` for some reason.

I was calling method A, which called method B, which called the web request.

I skipped method B and went from A to WEB directly and now speeds are great.